# Getting find: truncate: No such file or directory error

Tags: bash

I need to find the files for a specific year for eg- 2014 and empty the files. Trying to use the below command which is throwing

```
touch -t 201401010000 /tmp/from 
touch -t 201501010000 /tmp/to
find . -type f -newer /tmp/from ! -newer /tmp/to  -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;

error :- find: truncate: No such file or directory
```

Is there any syntax error i am making in the above command and how can i rectify the same.
Thanks

Comment: (1) what system do you use? Is it GNU truncate and find or some other version? (2) can you paste files found by find command somewhere? I suspect you have some path, which was treated as two separate paths by truncate (perhaps because of '\' or space or tab in name); my test with file with spaces in path worked with GNU truncate, but you might've hit different edge case.

Comment: what does `which truncate` say? maybe you don't have it installed

Comment: it shows no truncate and it gives the directory paths.

Comment: Ugh, it should come with GNU coreutils - what OS do you use?

Comment: Which distribution then? Did you change your path in any way? (on all Linux distributions, that I know truncate is installed by default)

Answer (score 1):

Got the above scenario to work by the command below.

```
find . -type f -newermt 2014-01-01 ! -newermt 2015-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Thanks everyone for the suggestion.